# Automatic hist with R per factor

Tags: r, render

I have this data:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(Location = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), duration.hours.mean_2006 = c(14.0623159303882, 
12.4725490196078, 7.03333333333333, 34.5672181372549), duration.hours.mean_2007 = c(13.0378277153558, 
9.99890350877193, 9.63827160493827, 33.0019047619048), duration.hours.mean_2008 = c(12.9337023370234, 
12.6810699588477, 11.2606060606061, 34.5296875), duration.hours.mean_2009 = c(12.5025960539979, 
10.9380407124682, 11.7544715447154, 34.1690476190476), duration.hours.mean_2014 = c(95.175, 
95.175, 95.175, 95.175)), .Names = c("Location", "duration.hours.mean_2006", 
"duration.hours.mean_2007", "duration.hours.mean_2008", "duration.hours.mean_2009", 
"duration.hours.mean_2014"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to render histograms for each of the factor "location": one for a, another one for b, another for c, etc. So on the X-axis I would have the duration.hours.mean_2006, duration.hours.mean_2007, etc.

Is there a way to do something like automatically? Building the hist is not an issue, the loop thing is the problem. I could not relevant questions / articles on internet for now!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyr)    
test <- gather(df, key = "year", value = "duration_value_mean", 2:6)
ggplot(test, aes(x = duration_value_mean)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) + facet_wrap(~ Location)
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HJ7w.png)

Comment: when using ggplot: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'duration_value_mean' not found

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand how to you intend to have histogram for each location and each duration as there are only one values each and not a distribution of data. But what you can have from this data is something like: 
[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
test<-reshape2::melt(df,"Location")
ggplot(test,aes(variable,value,fill=Location))+geom_col()+coord_flip()
```

For separate plots for each location on same panel:

```
ggplot(test,aes(variable,value,fill=Location))+geom_col()+coord_flip()+
  facet_wrap(~ Location)
```

[image]
Or you can subset the data by location and then plot.

```
library(dplyr)
a<-test %>%
  filter(Location=="a")
b<-test %>%
  filter(Location=="b")
c<-test %>%
  filter(Location=="c")
d<-test %>%
  filter(Location=="d")

p1<-ggplot(a,aes(variable,value))+geom_col(fill="red")+coord_flip()#Plot for 'a' Location
p2<-ggplot(b,aes(variable,value))+geom_col(fill="green")+coord_flip()#Plot for 'b' Location
p3<-ggplot(c,aes(variable,value))+geom_col(fill="blue")+coord_flip()#Plot for 'c' Location
p4<-ggplot(d,aes(variable,value))+geom_col(fill="grey")+coord_flip()#Plot for 'd' Location
p1 #Plot for 'a' Location
```

[image]

Comment: I meant to render an histogram for each of the location. And I would save each of the hist in JPEG to use in a report.